# Is it even possible to correct my LVM mistakes?

Tags: lvm, storage, proxmox

I have this Proxmox (PVE) installation on an old server and I wanted to swap the old drives in order to get more space. But first I wanted to move the PVE installation to an SSD. *Simple enough.*

Starting Point:

- 1x76GB SATA (PVE Root LVM)
- 2x500GB SATA (VG1 configured as RAID1 with mdadm - LVM Thinpool)

End Goal:

- 1x120GB SSD (PVE Root LVM)
- 2x500GB SATA (VG1 for a while longer)
- 1x2000GB SATA* (in VG1 in order to `pvmove` all files to this drive from the old RAID)

*This drive is to be configured in an mdraid setup with another 2TB drive which is to be added at a later time (due to lack of cables and SATA ports).

I inserted the SSD and booted up a live USB with Linux, ran a dd command I found online to copy the old 76GB drive to the new (but used) 120GB SSD. This worked out ok, apart from the disk still showing 76GB in size.

So to fix this I'm not exactly sure what I did in hindsight. Looking at the history I believe I ran the following commands

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/0\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan
parted -l
 # At this point I got a few questions and I chose Fix and/or Ignore until it was finished
pvresize /dev/sda3
lvresize /dev/pve/data -l 100%FREE
```

Now I thought I was done and started working with my next item on the list. *This is where I met my late night brain Stu Pid.*

I created the RAID with the one drive

```
mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level 1 --raid-devices 2 /dev/sdd missing
 # Next, I forgot to RTFM..
mkfs.ext4 /dev/md2
 # I actually aborted the above command Ctrl-C...
 # Uhhhh. I create the Physical Volume and extended the VG
pvcreate /dev/md2
vgextend vg1 /dev/md2
 # Next, I dunno
lvextend /dev/vg1/tpool /dev/md2
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg1-tpool
 # Again what? And now something from Youtube
/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf > /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
dpkg-reconfigure pve-kernel-`uname -r`
```

From this point I, for some reason, ran `parted -l` again and `resize2fs` on the `vg1-tpool`. All I know is that I don't know what I'm doing at this point.

So to sum up, this is what I end up with (some info omitted for brevity):

```
root@host:~# lsblk
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sda1                           8:1    0  1007K  0 part
├─sda2                           8:2    0   512M  0 part
└─sda3                           8:3    0 111.3G  0 part
  ├─pve-swap                   253:0    0     8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root                   253:1    0  18.5G  0 lvm   /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta             253:2    0     1G  0 lvm
  │ └─pve-data-tpool           253:4    0  82.8G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-data               253:5    0  82.8G  0 lvm
  │   ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0   253:6    0    15G  0 lvm
  │   └─pve-vm--103--disk--0   253:7    0     4G  0 lvm
  └─pve-data_tdata             253:3    0  82.8G  0 lvm
    └─pve-data-tpool           253:4    0  82.8G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-data               253:5    0  82.8G  0 lvm
      ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0   253:6    0    15G  0 lvm
      └─pve-vm--103--disk--0   253:7    0     4G  0 lvm
sdb                              8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sdb1                           8:17   0 465.8G  0 part
  └─md1                          9:1    0 465.7G  0 raid1
    ├─vg1-tpool_tmeta          253:8    0   108M  0 lvm
    │ └─vg1-tpool-tpool        253:10   0   2.3T  0 lvm
    │   ├─vg1-tpool            253:11   0   2.3T  0 lvm
    │   ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--0 253:12   0    32G  0 lvm
    │   ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--1 253:13   0   350G  0 lvm
    │   └─vg1-vm--101--disk--0 253:14   0    32G  0 lvm
    └─vg1-tpool_tdata          253:9    0   2.3T  0 lvm
      └─vg1-tpool-tpool        253:10   0   2.3T  0 lvm
        ├─vg1-tpool            253:11   0   2.3T  0 lvm
        ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--0 253:12   0    32G  0 lvm
        ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--1 253:13   0   350G  0 lvm
        └─vg1-vm--101--disk--0 253:14   0    32G  0 lvm
sdc                              8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sdc1                           8:33   0 465.8G  0 part
  └─md1                          9:1    0 465.7G  0 raid1
    ├─vg1-tpool_tmeta          253:8    0   108M  0 lvm
    │ └─vg1-tpool-tpool        253:10   0   2.3T  0 lvm
    │   ├─vg1-tpool            253:11   0   2.3T  0 lvm
    │   ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--0 253:12   0    32G  0 lvm
    │   ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--1 253:13   0   350G  0 lvm
    │   └─vg1-vm--101--disk--0 253:14   0    32G  0 lvm
    └─vg1-tpool_tdata          253:9    0   2.3T  0 lvm
      └─vg1-tpool-tpool        253:10   0   2.3T  0 lvm
        ├─vg1-tpool            253:11   0   2.3T  0 lvm
        ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--0 253:12   0    32G  0 lvm
        ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--1 253:13   0   350G  0 lvm
        └─vg1-vm--101--disk--0 253:14   0    32G  0 lvm
sdd                              8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─md2                            9:2    0   1.8T  0 raid1
  └─vg1-tpool_tdata            253:9    0   2.3T  0 lvm
    └─vg1-tpool-tpool          253:10   0   2.3T  0 lvm
      ├─vg1-tpool              253:11   0   2.3T  0 lvm
      ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--0   253:12   0    32G  0 lvm
      ├─vg1-vm--100--disk--1   253:13   0   350G  0 lvm
      └─vg1-vm--101--disk--0   253:14   0    32G  0 lvm

root@host:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               pve
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  VG Size               <111.29 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              28489
  Alloc PE / Size       28489 / <111.29 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg1
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  VG Size               2.27 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              596101
  Alloc PE / Size       596101 / 2.27 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0

root@host:~# lvdisplay vg1
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                tpool
  VG Name                vg1
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time host, 2020-09-11 00:05:40 +0200
  LV Pool metadata       tpool_tmeta
  LV Pool data           tpool_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 4
  LV Size                2.27 TiB
  Allocated pool data    15.16%
  Allocated metadata     50.58%
  Current LE             596047
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:10
```

[image: From Proxmox environment]

What are the actual mistakes and how could I fix them? It seems like I've somehow allocated all the extents on every VG, So now I can't really do anything! Again, Is it still possible to:

- Get the "free space" back, whatever that means
- Fix /dev/md2 so that I can `pvmove` from /dev/md1 properly

Comment: You allocated physical volumes and LVM accepted them. If you check the LV space usage, you ought to find that you have quite a lot of allocated but unused space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanted a VG named *vg1*, consisting of two RAIDs. The two small disks form /dev/md1, the large disk forms /dev/md2. Judging from the `lsblk` output and the screenshot, this is what you have. **Good!** Although perhaps LVM's built-in mirroring might be a better solution (simpler, probably less flexible).

Now, things become very strange. You make a file system on /dev/md2, which you throw away by turning the device into a physical volume. You add /dev/md2 to the volume group (OK) and extend *tpool* over the entire size of *vg1*. That's fine, but you should not be surprised that all your space is used up if you extend a logical volume to use all your space.

Even stranger, after extending *tpool*, you run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg1-tpool` on it. This should actually result in an error, since there is no filesystem on that volume. Or perhaps you have left out a few steps?

To get free space in *vg1*, I would simply reduce the size of that volume to what it was before. Normally, this should work, hoping that any thin volumes that might use *tpool* have not seen much activity.

Lastly, I would definitely not use random tutorials and Youtube videos for tasks that I don't understand and that have the potential to annihilate my server. Read a thorough introduction to LVM, thin volumes and filesystems before you try again.

Comment: In case `resize2fs` didn't emit an error, perhaps there is indeed a filesystem on *tpool*. This would be weird, since thinpool volumes are not supposed to have filesystems; their purpose is to be a storage pool for thin volumes. If there is a filesystem on *tpool*, you have to unmont it, then reduce its size before `lvreduce`. Or run `lvreduce -r` after unmounting.

Comment: I believe many of the commands, as you said, produced an error message. I'm going to backup my VMs and try and try what you are suggesting. With VMs running in the TPool I guess this is not possible to do while they are online.

Comment: You can reduce the size of a logical volume while it is in use. What you can't do is reducing  a mounted filesystem. If *tpool* is indeed a thinpool, I see hope.

Comment: I decided to move all VMs that could fit on the SSD - and start from scratch with the larger disks. I'm going to read up on how to manage LVM in proxmox. seems to be slightly more to it than an ordinary setup.